# How to publish site to Azure without stopping site first

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a site running on Azure.

When I publish from Visual Studio, I get an error message saying a file is in use.

If I then stop the site, and then publish again, and then start, everything is fine.

However, I would like to not be required to log into Azure and do this every time an update is made to the site.

Is there a way to do this?

This is the error message:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Web deployment task failed. (Web Deploy cannot modify the file 'GGL.OrderEntry.Data.dll' on the destination because it is locked by an external process.  In order to allow the publish operation to succeed, you may need to either restart your application to release the lock, or use the AppOffline rule handler for .Net applications on your next publish attempt.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_FILE_IN_USE.) GGL.OrderEntry      0

The DLL is a project in the solution.

Comment: What file is it? I suppose it's a data-file or something similar. In general Azure App Services ( i.e. IIS )  do not lock application files: aspx, dll, etc. If you have a data-file, consider to store it somewhere else (Blob storage?).

Comment: Interesting, I will check this out further to see exactly what is getting locked.

Comment: I edited the question to show the dll that is getting locked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to publish an `app_offline.htm` file to the root of the site. This uses an IIS feature to stop the application pool if it sees a file like this, which should release the locks and serve this file instead.

Another way would be to use Deployment Slots. You can stop the "staging" slot and publish to that. Then do a slot swap to get it to production. This has the added benefit of less downtime for users.

Deployment slots do need a Standard plan though.

Comment: app_offline.htm - I had no idea this existed. That's pretty handy, especially when you have to deploy breaking schema changes to a database and slot swapping is therefore insufficient for the deployment. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Does app_offline.htm get removed automatically after the publish is complete?  Or do I manually remove it?

Comment: If I remember correctly, you have to delete it after publish